# hand deliver UK visa application to UKVI in Manhattan, New York

Tags: uk, shipping

Question about UK visa shipping -

Can I hand deliver my UK visa application, including the biometric confirmation receipt, to UKVI in Manhattan, New York? (I live nearby.)

If not, should I just buy a round trip shipping label from UPS to the address below?

VFS Services USA Inc. 
UKVI Scanning Hub 
750 Third Avenue 
Suite 946 
New York 
NY 10017

Thanks very much.

Comment: How long did it take before you got your visa stamped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, UKVI at the British Consulate New York is not open to the public, and visa
applications are not accepted or returned in person, only by mail.

You can purchase shipping/return service independently or through [VFS Global](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/premium-services), following the directions in the [application centre](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) package.

Comment: This must have changed! I remember handing off my student visa in the UK consulate in NYC about 9 years ago

Comment: thanks very much! And can I buy the shipping labels after my biometric appointment?